# mkdir permission error while importing oracledb@3.0.0 with Node@10.9.0

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

While I am trying to import **oracledb@3.0.0** using **Node 10.9.0**, I am getting below error,

```
oracledb Beginning installation
oracledb Verifying installation
oracledb Continuing installation
oracledb ERR! NJS-054: Binary build/Release/oracledb.node was not installed.
oracledb ERR! Failed to install binary package oracledb-v3.0.0-node-abi64-linux-x64.gz
oracledb ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'build'
oracledb ERR! For help see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#troubleshooting
```

Since above code seems to be permission issue, I also tried **sudo npm i mypck@3.2.0** but then it gives below error

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

**Question:**

How can I give permission to create directory or execute command **npm** with **sudo** rights, any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize `--unsafe-perm=true` and `--allow-root` flags with npm install.

```
npm install -g oracledb@3.0.0 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

You can read more o this here : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions